# Show seconds on input type=date-local in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, input

In google chrome if I set the value of an input of type `datetime-local` to a time containing seconds where the seconds value is 0 Chrome decides not to show the seconds value on the input, meaning the user can't set the seconds at all.

E.g. If I set the value to `2013-10-24T20:36:01` then Chrome will show an input and the user can change the day, month, year, hours, minutes and seconds to whatever they want (including 0). If I set the value to `2013-10-24T20:36:00` then the seconds part disappears. I can understand it not being shown if no value for seconds was passed in but I am explicitly setting them to 0 so I would have assumed it would show them.

The reason why this is a problem is because I am reading the times from a database and if any of them have been set to 0 seconds the user can't change the time without hacking it with developer tools!

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Adding step attribute will resolve your issue.

```
<input type=datetime-local value="2013-10-24T20:36:00" step="1">
```

The default value of step attribute is 60 (one minute).

Comment: Somehow this doesn't always work. It seems as if I'm editing the hour/minute values while the seconds field is 00, it's dropped on submit while if I leave the field unedited, the 00-seconds is passed as should.

Comment: As I understand it, adding step for datetime-local or time types brings seconds. but if I add the step for the date type, it skips as many days as the number I added in the step. I did not know that.

Answer (score 3):

## 05 2022

It's been quite sometime and you must have gone ahead, but if anyone came here and looking for a simpler solution then try this

Chrome ver: `Version 100.0.4896.127`

```html
<input type="time" step="1" name="timeinput">
```

This will output hr:min:sec

Comment: `type="time"` is a different input as it only includes Time, not Date

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I made a workaround that is pretty simple, my issue was validation so It doesnt fit directly, but could be a springboard

```
        function dateMachRegex(date) {
            const regex = /^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})$/g;
            if (date.match(regex)) {
                return true;
            } else if ((date+":00").match(regex)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```