# Is there a native HTML date time picker with seconds?

Tags: html, datetimepicker

Is there any way to include seconds in the HTML date time picker?

```
<input type="datetime-local" />
```

Comment: are you trying for something like this?? http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/AXPEPB

Comment: Yes, yours shows seconds but I cannot pick them. I want to choose seconds too

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like this has an answer here, using the "step" property: [Show seconds on input type=date-local in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504018/show-seconds-on-input-type-date-local-in-chrome)

Setting `step=1` will display seconds on the picker:

```
<input type=datetime-local step=1>
```

Some doc for the step can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_datetime-local_step.asp

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Brilliant. Thanks!